# Execution of .sql file through sqltool utility in hsqldb

Tags: hsqldb, sqltools

I am trying to execute the demofeature_enable.sql file through the following way.

```
    java -jar sqltool.jar --inlineRC=url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9999/bwdb,user=sa,password= demofeature_enable.sql
```

The above command is throwing follwoing error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Error: could not match input
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.sqltool.SqlFileScanner.zzScanError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.sqltool.SqlFileScanner.yylex(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlFile.scanpass(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlFile.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool.objectMain(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Any help would be highly appreciable?

Comment: Please attach here demofeature_enable.sql, I guess you have there some SQL statement which isn't terminated by ';'